# Como gerar uma iso da versão atual do meu ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: linux, backup

Qual a melhor solução para gerar uma imagem iso de forma simples (preferencialmente linha de comando) na ultima versao LTS do ubuntu (18.04) que esta instalado no meu computador.

Meu objetivo é ter uma versão que eu possa instalar no meu computador e ter de volta o estado atual com todos os aplicativos instalados e configurações que fiz de maneira simples.

Comment: Essa pergunta deveria ser feita no https://askubuntu.com/ .

Answer (score 1):

Use o Pinguy Builder

Instale o pacote pinguybuilder_5.1-8_all.deb disponível [aqui](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pinguy-os/files/ISO_Builder/)

```
sudo dpkg -i pinguybuilder_5.1-8_all.deb
```

Então rode o programa via linha de comando (irá imprimir um help explicando as opções)

```
sudo PinguyBuilder
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ou, se prefirir, pela interface gráfica

```
sudo PinguyBuilder-gtk
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: gostei da solução, mas porque usar a versão 5.1-8_all e não a versão 5.2-1_all.deb ?

Comment: Você tem razão, a versão mais nova também deve funcionar. É que fiz os testes na versão 5.1-8_all.